# Timed out waiting for process for running app from android studio to Temi that is connected wirelessly

Tags: android, android-studio, wifi

My laptop is connected to Temi Robot via same wifi SSID but for some reason I kept getting timed out:

> 07/01 15:33:46: Launching 'app' on rockchip rk3288.
> Timed out waiting
> for process (org.pytorch.demo.PatientPotentialFallDetection) to appear
> on rockchip-rk3288-192.168.160.46:5555.
> Install successfully finished
> in 4 m 39 s 233 ms.

And no the app did not appear on Temi's screen. And Temi doesn't have any USB port for wired connection.

This happened suddenly, previously I did not have the issue before for some reason I found my ML model missing, put it back in and such problems appeared. Not sure if the model thing is the cause of the problem as it is only 58 MB.

Edit:

[Timed out waiting for process to appear on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58245771/timed-out-waiting-for-process-to-appear-on-device)

Tried this Similar question's suggestions but they did not pan out.

Edit:

Downgrading from java 11 to 8 did help me run the app on Temi but for some reason when I put on  the ML model back in the poject, timeout error occurs again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason suddenly it is working for now, I don't know what happened. But it takes two minute to load the app to Temi robot.

Sorry for anyone web searching an answer for this.

Edit: My hypothesis is that it might be because there are too much gradle dependencies that I have  to install over wifi. I tried to install a fresh app with little dependencies and it installed over the air much faster