# Time out waiting for process after react-native migration

Tags: android, react-native

I have migrated a react-native app from 0.62.1 to 0.66.3
I used [react-native helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.63.2&to=0.66.3)

Build is ok but app doesn't launch, and I have this error

> Timed out waiting for process (com.xxxxx.yyyyyy) to appear on Nexus_6_API_27 [emulator-5554].

I have tried all solutions on this [SO similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58245771/timed-out-waiting-for-process-to-appear-on-device) :

- Differents devices
- Differents cable link (2.0, 3.0...)
- Emulator / Real device
- Wipe node modules
- Restart phone / computer
- Clear / invalidate cache
- Install last version of Android-Studio

Any idea ?